# Multiple transition effects with TextViews (Android)

Tags: android, textview, transition

I would like 3 TextViews to appear in sequence (the first one, then when it has finished the second one, and then the third one). I tried this code

```
tv1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
tv2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
tv3.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
```

but they appear together, so I tried

```
tv1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
tv2.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(1000).setDuration(1000);
tv3.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(2000).setDuration(1000);
```

but when I open the app they appear together with no animation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set alpha to 0 before start animation

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it.

If you want this by using alpha value, every view you animate must have **0.0f** alpha value at the beginning. Then animate them to **1.0f** alpha.

For example:

```
private void animateViews(final ArrayList<View> viewArrayList, long delay){
    for (int i = 0; i < viewArrayList.size(); i++) {
        final int position = i;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewArrayList.get(position).animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200);
            }
        }, i * delay);
    }
}
```

You can use this method I wrote.

Usage:

```
ArrayList<View> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(tv1);
arrayList.add(tv2);
arrayList.add(tv3);
animateViews(arrayList,300);
```

delay parameter means, every animation start 300 * index miliseconds delayed.
Also this method has 200 ms duration for alpha animation.

First starts at 0 delay,

Second starts at 1 * 300 ms delay

Third starts at 2 * 300 ms delay

...

..

.

Answer (score 1):

Add an AnimationListener and start the next animation when the previous one ends.

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f,0f);
alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
alphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim)
    {
    };
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim)
    {
    };
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
    {
        nextPuzzle();
    };
}); 
tv1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the time

```
tv1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
tv2.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(2000).setDuration(1000);
tv3.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(3000).setDuration(1000);
```